# Can I create a new array reference which contains a subset of an existing array, without copying memory?

Tags: c#, arrays, memory, buffer, subset

I am building a file reader in C#, and large volumes of data will be enumerated.  I want to use the same buffer for each element I read out, then pass the buffer on for further processing by the client.  The API would be cleaner if I could return a `byte[]` of the correct size, rather than the raw buffer and a length.

Is it possible to do this in C# without copying memory?

Comment: What about passing a [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/63z365ty.aspx) that is based on a certain region of the original buffer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `ArraySegment<T>`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d.aspx

That lets you specify the start and end of the segment you want to pass on without copying any data.

Answer (score 4):

If you can change your API parameter types, I think you could use an [ArraySegment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[`ArraySegment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d.aspx) type is a generic struct that allows us to store information about an array range. It is useful for storing array ranges. The `ArraySegment` facilitates optimizations that reduce memory copying and heap allocations.

From *MSDN*;

> The Array property returns the entire original array, not a copy of
>   the array; therefore, changes made to the array returned by the Array
>   property are made to the original array.

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/uRRmoi).